# Laravel 5 seeders: how to use autoincrement field from one seeder in another?

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration, seeding, laravel-5

Example: I have 2 models: `Book` and `Author`. Each book has only one author.
Book id is an autoincrement key.

So I have to use 2 seeders: `BookTableSeeder` and `AuthorTableSeeder`. They are in different classes: `BookTableSeeder` and `AuthorTableSeeder`.

So first I seed `books`, then I seed `authors`.
How can I seed books, if books use author ids?

Comment: Seed the data together, this will allow you to use the id and allow you to relate them together. Or seed authors first followed by their books. Or just think of it in a logical way, a book will never exist without an author.

Comment: @MattBurrow it was just an example. In real word all the models (almost) are related. Does it mean that all seeds should be in one file?

Comment: If the data is related yes. But, if you want to seed in separate classes, the best way to go about it would be to manually enter the ids yourself. Keeping in-mind seeding is mainly used for populating dummy-data or initial data for the application.

Comment: In your book seeder you could have something like `$authors = Author::lists('id')`, now you could seed author_id with `$faker->randomElement($authors)` or something similar in plain php. If you need to seed books first, you could replace the $faker portion with `mt_rand(1,50)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense seed books before authors, since books needs authors.

You can try something like this on the BookTable Seeder, creating authors first and after that you can create book:

```
$book->author = Author::where('name', 'Shakespeare')->first();
```

Also it doesn't make sense for each author to only have one book